# delaying in running thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am new in android and i ask a question about my thread that i create. I think it is stupid question but I am sorry.I have a onClick button listener. Its job is get the URL download link and stores in a variable.

```
   /**
 * this method invoke from setPositiveButton's dialog
 *
 * @param rootView
 */
private void addURLToList(View rootView) {

    editTextAddURL = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_add_url);

    Log.i("===", "addURLToList: " + editTextAddURL.getText());
    stringUrl = editTextAddURL.getText().toString();

     *start GetSizeOfFile thread for getting size file and store
     * in lenghtOfFile variable
     */
    new GetSizeOfFile().start();

    Log.i("====", "size of file after Thread: " + lenghtOfFile);


}
```

I create a Thread because I want to get file size.

```
  private class GetSizeOfFile extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            Log.i("====", "size of file in Thread: " + lenghtOfFile);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

everything is ok but when thread is started ,after few second my lenghtOfFile variable is initialized and I got 0 in `lenghtOfFile` in this Line `Log.i("====", "size of file after Thread: " + lenghtOfFile);`
this is my logcat:

```
02-22 10:02:11.352 11333-11333/com.example.manifest.simplefiledownloadmanager I/===: addURLToList: http://dl2.soft98.ir/soft/a/Adobe.Shockwave.Player.12.2.7.197.IE.rar
02-22 10:02:11.352 11333-11333/com.example.manifest.simplefiledownloadmanager I/====: file name : Adobe.Shockwave.Player.12.2.7.197.IE.rar
02-22 10:02:11.352 11333-11333/com.example.manifest.simplefiledownloadmanager I/====: size of file after Thread: 0
02-22 10:02:36.544 11333-11495/com.example.manifest.simplefiledownloadmanager I/====: size of file in Thread: 13524394
```

I want to get file's size from thread first.is it correct that I have to sleep the thread or exit standard way?sorry I am new in android

Comment: as usual ... create callback, call callback from "the end of thread", do the staff which needs results from Thread in the calback ... waiting for thread results inside `addURLToList` makes Thread useless (yeah, I know NetworkOnMainThreadExcpetion ... but that's why it was made ... for not blocking the main thread)

Comment: I don't know why some people give minus to some post?I am new in android If you don't want to answer me then don't answer, why give minus!!!!

Comment: @Selvin thank you. can you send a tutorial link about you way?

Comment: Use the AsyncTask, to achieve the same. Checkout below example.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog?rq=1

Comment: Use the AsyncTask, to achieve the same. Checkout below example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog?rq=1

Comment: @VijaykumarChiniwar thank you .

Answer (score 0):

When working with threads you cannot assume their order of execution.

What happens in your case I presume is that while your new thread is waiting on the connection to be established, the original thread is being run with the uninitialized `lenghtOfFile` variable so the log looks like it does. Another possibility is that the new thread didn't even begin running when the `lenghtOfFile=0` line was logged. That is just how threads work.

For this exact purpose the [ASyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class exists in Android.
Your code should be somewhat like this:

```
private class GetSizeOfFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Long> {

     // runs on a background thread
     protected Long doInBackground(String... stringUrls) {
         String stringUrl = stringUrls[0];
         try {
             URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
             HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             long lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
             return lenghtOfFile;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return -1;
     }

     // runs on main thread
     protected void onPostExecute(Long lenghtOfFile) {
        if (lenghtOfFile == -1) {
            // something went wrong
        } else {
            Log.i("====", "size of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
            // whatever else you want to do
        }
     }
}

new GetSizeOfFile().execute(stringUrl);
```